# how to open spinner as a dialog in android version 3.0 above?

Tags: android

when i click on spinner it opens like drop down in newer android devices and same thing open like dialog in older version. i want my spinner to be open as a dialog in newer version also.
please help.

i have tries below code but it opens spinner a drop down in newer versions

```
ArrayList<Integer> hourarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
hoursView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hoursview);
for (int i = 00; i <= 24; i++) {
        hourarray.add(i);
    }
hoursView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item, hourarray));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your `Spinner` in Layout file.

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

If You want like a dropdown in All version Add this

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```